# paypal sandbox proxy error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I just registered to paypal sandbox in order to use digital goods feature on my website.
I did all the steps required for registering and for creating an express checkout form through the paypal integration wizard (https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/)

My problem is now when I click the pay with paypal button I get a pop up screen saying:

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
> The proxy server could not handle the request GET >/webapps/checkout/webflow/sparta/expresscheckoutincontextinitflow.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

I hope someone could help me figure this out.
The API information I used was taken from my sandbox test account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting the same thing for a few days now. I can't make any test payment on sandbox. Moving away from paypal as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a performance issue.
Wait a few minutes and try again.